# How can I have the date in french locale

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this function to have a date in a document

```
Utilities.formatDate(datejdc, "CEST","EEEE, dd MMMMM yy");
```

I would like to have the date in French

How can I change the locale in google apps script ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible directly but it is quite simple to write a script in JS to get that result.

Example :

```
function frenchDate(date) {
  var month = ['janvier','février','mars','avril','mai','juin','juillet','août','septembre','octobre','novembre','décembre'];
  var day = ['dimanche','lundi','mardi','mercredi','jeudi','vendredi','samedi'];
  var m = month[date.getMonth()];
  var d = day[date.getDay()];
  var dateStringFr = d+' '+date.getDate()+' '+m+' '+date.getFullYear();
  return dateStringFr
}

function test(){
Logger.log(frenchDate(new Date()));
}
```

Logger result : `[13-11-18 17:49:33:816 CET] lundi 18 novembre 2013`

for details about date methods see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for example